# Javascript not able to print large string

Tags: javascript, php

I am entirely new to JavaScript and the only reason I need it now is to update a picture on a PHP page. The picture is in Base64. This is the code I currently have:

```
if($data != null){
    $data = "data:image/jpeg;base64, " . $data;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myvar = "<?php echo ($data); ?>";
    document.write("test" + myvar);
</script>
```

This simply does not output anything.
However, if I try something like this:

```
if($data != null){
    $data = "data:image/jpeg;base64, " . $data;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("test" + "<?php echo strlen($data); ?>");
</script>
```

it does work and outputs a number somewhere between 10.000 and 20.000. I read on the internet that there is not really a max variable size in JavaScript, atleast not one I am able to reach with this size. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not "echo" with PHP direct? EDIT: Are you missing the IMG html TAG?

Comment: @lcssanches this was just a test to get an output from Javascript. `echo`'ing direcly from PHP does work, but ultimately I am trying to change the src from an image using this code: `document.getElementById("img1").src="<?php echo ($data); ?>";`

Comment: 20K is far far far from any limit if ever exists. Did you check your page source (inside the browser)? Nothing there?

Comment: Also try this: <?php
if($data != null){ 
    $data = "data:image/jpeg;base64, " . $data;
}


echo "PHP things <br />";
echo "Len: ".strlen($data)."<br />";
echo "<pre>$data</pre>";
echo "<hr>"

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myvar = "<?=$data?>";

    document.write("JS things <br />");
    document.write("Len: " + myvar.length+ " <br />");

    document.write("<pre>" + myvar + "</pre>");

</script>

Comment: @lcssanches I tested your code, it didn't do anything at first, but when I changed `$data` to `$data = "test"` it worked as it should. I screenshotted the output: [link](https://gyazo.com/999eefbf51a7a115f829109c08715317) and [link](https://gyazo.com/79c46860a6e10d797e2508ec5fb3897f)

Comment: Executing my version, is there any error on browser console (F12)?

Comment: @lcssanches Yes, I am getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`, for each time the code is ran.

Comment: OK, please run my version and share the PAGE SOURCE here http://pastebin.com/,

Comment: @lcssanches I found it. The string contained a newline symbol -.-'. Removing it was the way to go. Thanks alot for the help! Wouldn't have figured it out without you!

Comment: Glad you make it! #SOreadytohelp